# Disable OSX 10.10 dashboard

Tags: macos, performance, dashboard, usability

I noticed that my dashboard was using 25% of my cpu on osx 10.10 after I upgraded... now I want to disable the thing altogether because I never use it and it is doing two things that I do not like, first it is slowing my computer needlessly, secondly it constantly gets in the way when I want to switch desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Mission Control in System Preferences, there is an selection menu labeled Dashboard. Click on that selection menu and choose Off. Here's a screenshot: [image: Turn Dashboard Off]

Answer (score 0):

For you command line junkies, this would be:

> defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean yes

And then also, I think you have to reset the dock:

> killall -1 Dock

Not like the GUI method is tough, but this is nice if you want to write a configuration script or something.